# Adding a lookup field in zoho books that is a custom field in zoho CRM

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge, zohobooks, deluge

I am using zoho books and zoho CRM where I have a custom module in zoho CRM which I want to add as a lookup field in a zoho books module.

A direction for the deluge script required or an inbuilt way (if there is any) to add it in zoho books.